# What is the complexity of std::string::substr member function?

Tags: c++

What is the complexity of `std::string::substr` member function? Is it defined by standard or implementation-defined?

Answer (score 5):

The C++11 standard does not define the performance characteristics of `substr`, either in 21.4.7.8 or anywhere else I could find. In practice you can almost certainly expect `O(n)` performance with `n` being the length of the result.

Answer (score 2):

A naïve implementation would be O(k) where k is the length of the resulting substring. std::string does not support copy-on-write. If you want O(1) substring operations, use a data structure such as a [Rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Actually some implementations of C++ do support std::string copy on write. The standard explicitly points out this is a valid implementation technique provided certain constraints are maintained.

Comment: Loved the data-structure Rope. Never knew such a thing existed

Answer (score 1):

This is all that standard has to say about it:

n3242, 21.4.7.8

> 1. Requires: `pos <= size()`
> 2. Throws: `out_of_range` if `pos > size()`
> 3. Effects: Determines the effective length `rlen` of the string to copy as the smaller 
>      of `n` and `size() - pos`
> 4. Returns: `basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>(data()+pos,rlen)`.

So the answer would be no, the complexity is not defined.

EDIT: Corrected as per n3242, pos > size not pos >= size