# Return substring starting from position past the end of string (C++)

Tags: c++, substr

The first parameter of C++ STL function substr(pos,n), pos, is said to have this behaviour.

> "If the position passed is past the end of the string, an out_of_range exception is thrown."

However, if I do something like

```
string s("ab");
cout<<s.substr(2,666)<<endl;
```

then no exception is thrown even though the pos=2 is by definition past the end of the string.

The string::end defines the position "after the last character in the string" as "past the end of the string."
I noticed the returned character is always the '\0'. My question is if this is standard behaviour and if I can count on the fact that an empty string is returned in this case. Thank you.

Comment: right. `s.substr(s.length(), 666)` would return `""` while `s.substr(s.length()+1, 666)` would throw exception.

Comment: But how is that possible? s.length() is the position past the end of string and thus should throw out_of_range exception according to the statement above.

Comment: Where did that quote come from? At best it's confusing.

Comment: I quoted from [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) and [string::end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/end/) which are both on the [http://www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual requirement is (§21.4.7.8):

```
1 Requires: pos <= size()
2 Throws: out_of_range if pos > size().
```

In your case, pos == size(), so you should never see an exception, and should always get an empty string.

Comment: Is this the C++11 requirement or the C++03/98 requirement?

Comment: @NicolBolas: That quote is from the C++11 standard, but C++98/03 has the same requirement (just a different section number: §21.3.6.7).

Comment: I just ran over a different thread which says this.
`1 Requires: pos <= size()
2 Throws: out_of_range if pos >= size()`
I think it might be different standard, right?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449298/what-is-the-complexity-of-stdstringsubstr-member-function]

Comment: @user1459339, that user misquoted n3242.  I just looked it up and it is pos > size() so I edited his answer.  Check for yourself here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

Comment: @user1459339 that requirement could not be valid no matter how you look at it. It requires pos to be less **or equal** to size, while it throws if pos is greater **or equal** to size.

Comment: That is true. I did not notice that..tx

Answer (score 2):

Since the character at the position passed as the first parameter is included in the result, position `2` should not be considered to be *past* the end of the string: it is *at* the end of the string. The length of the string is a legal argument to pass to `substr`.