# What is the runtime of string::substr() in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the complexity of std::string::substr member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449298/what-is-the-complexity-of-stdstringsubstr-member-function)

I am attempting a naive solution to the common substring problem.  I do this by first finding all the substrings of the first string and adding them to a hash set.  Then, I find the substrings of the second string and see if they exist in the hash set, and adjust the longest substring if the length is greater than the current max substring.  What I was wondering is: what is the runtime of substr, in terms of the length of the `str1` (let's say `str1` has length `n`)?

```
#include<hash_set>

string longestCommonSubstring(string str1, string str2) {
    hash_set<string> substrings;
    string maxSubstring = "";
    int maxLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < str1.size(); j++) {
            substrings.insert(str1.substr(i,j-i));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < str2.size(); j++) {
            if (substrings.find(str2.substr(i,j-i)) != substrings.end()) {
                if (j-i > maxLength) {
                    maxSubstring = str2.substr(i,j-1);
                    maxLength = j - i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specified complexity for `substr`, but `string` has constant-time random access, and `substr` makes a new string of the given length, so it'll be essentially the cost of copying that many characters.

Note that GCC implements `std::string` with reference counting (illegally so), so the actual cost of making a copy may vary depending on your implementation.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, so what would you say the runtime of the algorithm is, O(n^3)?

Comment: Reference counting strings may be illegal in C++11 but the alternative is to make it impossible/horribly buggy to link against code built with an older GCC.

Comment: @ZanLynx: The correct solution for that would be to introduce a `__gnu_cxx::string98` which is link-compatible with the old C++98 G++ `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: sorry I misunderstood the question (I didn't read the question properly).

The time complexity is hardware dependent but it is reasonable to assume that it is proportional to the length of substring requested.

What the function does is just to create a copy of part of the original string.

Comment: That seems really pessimistic for allocation and copy. Care to explain why you think it's like this?